# Google Earth Engine - tile glitch when exporting GeoTIFF

Tags: google-earth-engine

I used GEE to export a GeoTIFF of WWF HydroSHEDS DEM (dataset here https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WWF_HydroSHEDS_03VFDEM, GEE script below).

I realized that when I import the DEM GeoTIFF to ArcGIS, a glitch shows at the edge of (what I believe are) the GEE tiles.[image] The glitch then disrupts the creation of Flow rasters (like Flow Accumulation here, only showing accumulations values 0 and 1).[image]Edit: the "tiles" seem to have a dimension of 0.025° x 0.025°.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a way to avoid it?

---

GEE code:

```
// WWF HydroSHEDS Void filled DEM 
// Global
// 3 arc-seconds (90m)
var scale = 90

var collection = 'WWF/HydroSHEDS/03VFDEM';
var band = 'b1';
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-75, 17.5],[-68, 17.5],[-68, 20.5],[-73.5, 20.5],[-75, 19],[-75, 17.5]]]);

var dataset = ee.Image(collection).select(band);
                //  .filterBounds(region);
print (dataset);

var elevationVis = {
  min: -50.0,
  max: 3000.0,
  gamma: 2.0,
};
Map.setCenter(-71, 18.5, 9);
Map.addLayer(
    dataset, elevationVis, collection);

// Exporting as geoTIFF, to personal Google Drive
var image = dataset
print('crs', dataset.select(0).projection()) // Use to get native projection
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : image,
  region : region,
  description : "HydroSHEDS", // Task name
  folder : 'ee',
  fileNamePrefix : 'WWF_HydroSHEDS_03VFDEM_EPSG3857', // File name
  scale : scale, // Size of cells in exported raster, in m - use same scale as native resolution
  crs : 'EPSG:3857'
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because the layer is rescaled when exporting with a different CRS than the native dataset. A similar issue has been answered here already:  [Black vertical lines on exported image from Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270233/black-vertical-lines-on-exported-image-from-google-earth-engine)